# Is there a slideshow plugin for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio plugin for viewing PowerPoint slide shows in a pane in Visual Studio? I've been working through a tutorial and I'm annoyed with alt-tabbing between the two applications (I prefer giving Visual Studio the full screen).

Clarification:

I do have dual screens at work, and a 30" display at home, but in my doubtless fussy opinion, opening and arranging multiple windows is much less convenient then having the info in a pane in the IDE for this particular task. There is also the matter being able to cut and paste code from the tutorial into the edit window without having to alt-tab. I'd like something like the internal web browser pane, or in-place help panes in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt there would be a VS plug-in for displaying PowerPoint slide shows. I can't imagine very many cases where this would be useful. I never use PowerPoint when doing development work.

Perhaps the only situation where it might be useful is in training, as you've described. But honestly, my recommendation would be to add a second monitor to your computer. Then you can keep Visual Studio maximized on your primary screen, while displaying the PowerPoint slides on the secondary monitor.

I suspect that you'll find a dual-screen setup will not only be useful while you're *learning* Visual Studio, but continue to pay dividends as you begin *working* in Visual Studio, as well. The productivity boost of multiple screens is [well documented](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/multiple-monitors-and-productivity.html) around the web, and my own experience is that I can hardly work without a *minimum* of 2 screens anymore.

> **This is really a no-brainer for any developer who values his or her time.** Now more than ever, since:
>
> 1. Most mainstream, inexpensive video cards tend to come with two VGA ports (aka "dual head") standard.
> 2. The price of less bulky 17" and 19" LCDs are quite reasonable.
> 3. Windows XP has mature multiple monitor support; it's been a standard out of box win32 feature since Windows 98.

The multiple monitor support is *very* good in both Windows XP and Windows 7 (I experienced some minor irritations under Windows Vista, but not nearly enough to be discouraging). And you don't have to buy a giant secondary screen (or even primary screen). Two 17" or 19" monitors will generally be more productive than one large 22" or 24" screen.

Comment: I am already set up with dual monitors. I've edited my question to make my goals a bit clearer.